# Cual es la manera mas eficiente de ver una DB desde android

Tags: android, base-de-datos, android-studio

Quisiera saber cual seria la forma mas eficiente de crear una app para android que lo unico que haga es consultar una base de datos en una computadora, la computadora tiene un software de inventario hecho con Visual Fox Pro, la base de datos del software es .DBf, quiero crear una app que simplemente consulte esa base de datos, no quiero ni editar ni agregar registros, solo que el la app tenga un textbox donde se ponga una consulta y esta muestre los resultados (Select "consulta" from "tabla") con que lenguaje seria mas conveniente programarla y cual seria la forma mas sencilla.

Comment: crea una rest API y consume la desde android u otras plataformas. saludos!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La forma en que comunmente se realiza esto en una aplicación android es a travez de un Web Service, puedes realizar un metodo que consulte el contenido de la base de datos.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/486s1yez(v=vs.80).aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hsf4sfs4(v=vs.80).aspx

Te recomiendo este ejemplo:

[Consumir Web Service en Android](http://www.ejemplosprogramacion.co/index.php/articulos/articulo/consumir-web-service-en-android-de-una-manera-sencilla/)